# REST API for 1 to 1 relationship

Tags: rest

Consider the following resources:

- Case -- a request to perform an amount of job steps
- Schedule -- a scheduling of job steps of a case

The relationship type between Case and Schedule is 1 to 1: a case can have only
one schedule (but may not have).

If a case already have a schedule the create request will completly override it.

How would it be better to design URI to create/retrieve a schedule for a case?

I'm trying to choose between

- PUT /cases/{case_id}/schedule
- GET /cases/{case_id}/schedule

and

- PUT /schedules/cases/{case_id}
- GET /schedules/cases/{case_id}

Could you please give advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first approach looks much better for me. The `schedule` is an attrribute of `case` and it doesn't make sence without the `case`.

Moreover you have said that `case` may not have schedule, so it will be better the first approach:

```
PUT /cases/{case_id}/schedule
GET /cases/{case_id}/schedule
```